Selenium: Python code stops compiling after dialog window pops up in IE
I've been trying to write a code that would download a csv file from my camera web service (available only on IE). Unfortunately as soon as it gets to confirm_button.click() the download dialog pops up and python hangs until I manually close the dialog. That way it executes the pyautogui part after it's no longer useful.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import pyautogui


options = webdriver.IeOptions()
options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

driver = webdriver.Ie(options=options)

driver.get("http://192.168.18.99")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
username_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username")))

if username_input.get_attribute('value') == '':
    username_input.send_keys(".....")

password_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_input.send_keys(".....")
login_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "b_login")
login_button.click()

config_tab = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "b_config")))
config_tab.click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "m_it_menu")))
m_it_menu = driver.find_element(By.ID, "m_it_menu")
if "ui-menu-item" in m_it_menu.get_attribute("class"):
    m_it_menu.click()

blackwhite_list_tab = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "m_blackwhite_list")))
blackwhite_list_tab.click()

bw_tab_title_white_tab = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bw_tab_title_white")))
bw_tab_title_white_tab.click()

export_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bw_export_white")))
export_button.click()

confirm_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "bw_exportEncrypt_confirm")))
confirm_button.click()

time.sleep(3)

pyautogui.write('C:\\Users\\...')
pyautogui.press('enter')

print("File saved successfully")

driver.quit()

I've been trying to mess around with IEDriver versions, TabProcGrowth values and AutoIt but nothing seems to work for me.
Can anyone help me with this issue?
